# Ubuntu boot freezes after GRUB (blank screen), but works after warm reboot from Windows

Tags: ubuntu, boot, dual-boot, grub, freeze

I have a peculiar situation concerning the boot process of Ubuntu 17.04 that I just can't figure out. On my HP Pavilion 13b-220nd I have installed both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04. My laptop boots in UEFI and secure boot is disabled as is fastboot in Windows.

**Scenario 1:**

When my laptop is turned off and I power it on GRUB appears and I have the option to pick Ubuntu or Windows. When I choose Ubuntu the display immediately turns black and the system freezes, it is non-responsive. There does not appear any text or a blinking cursor, neither with the boot parameters 'quiet' and 'splash' removed. I have to power the laptop down and restart.

**Scenario 2:**

I choose to boot Windows 10. At the login prompt I enter my credentials and login. Windows works flawlessly. When I choose to restart the system and return to GRUB and choose Ubuntu this time the same events as described in scenario 1 take place. I need to power down the laptop and then power it back on.

**However let's consider scenario 3:**

When in the GRUB menu I decide to boot Windows and at the login screen choose to restart (so I do not login to Windows) again I return to GRUB. This time when I choose to boot Ubuntu it works perfectly. Once in Ubuntu I can reboot as often as needed and the boot process runs perfectly.

Unfortunately there is, as far as I know, no way for me to retrieve any relevant logs from both scenario 1 or 2. What I can't get my head around is this....

What processes take place up until the Windows login screen that somehow enable booting Ubuntu upon restarting from that point. Something takes place that enables booting Ubuntu and which does not occur when trying to boot from a powered off state or when restarting the system from a logged in Windows environment. I can't figure this out on my own and the many hours spent scrolling through forums haven't helped either up until now

edit: the same applies to bootable/live USB's

Comment: I have figured out the cause of my problem. It is my wireless network card (BCM943142 b/g/n) apparently. After removing it Ubuntu boots perfectly both cold and warm. Now the question remains, what is it about this card that causes the boot process to freeze from a cold boot and not from a warm reboot.